# Как анимировать движение элемента вдоль svg-пути при прокрутке?

Tags: javascript, html, css3, svg, анимация

**У меня проблема:** Мне нужно изменить угловое положение элемента при прокрутке.
 Как и на моей веб-странице,- это длинный путь с фоном - и мне нужно анимировать движения автомобиля по этому пути во время скролла.

**Как на примере здесь:** `http://prinzhorn.github.io/skrollr-path/` - идеальное решение, отвечающее моим требованиям. Но, к сожалению, это очень устарело.

Может быть, у кого-то есть современная библиотека решений?
 Или кодовые идеи, как анимировать элемент через `svg-path` с прокруткой страницы?

Также я попробовал http://scrollmagic.io/examples/expert/bezier_path_animation.html - но это не то, что мне нужно, потому что мой `path` более сложный, а  не только пара кругов.

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [How to animate element along svg path on scroll?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50910459/7394871) от участника  [@brabertaser19](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1645431/brabertaser19).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/50910459/7394871

Answer (score 13):

Вот немного кода *vanilla* `JavaScript`, который перемещает "автомобиль" вдоль пути в зависимости от того, насколько страница прокрутилась.

Это  должно работать во всех современных браузерах. Часть кода, которую вам может потребоваться настроить, — это то, как мы получаем высоту страницы (`document.documentElement.scrollHeight`).

Возможно, вам придется использовать [разные методы](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1145850/how-to-get-height-of-entire-document-with-javascript) в зависимости от браузеров, которые вы хотите поддерживать.

```js
function positionCar() {
  var scrollY = window.scrollY || window.pageYOffset;
  var maxScrollY = document.documentElement.scrollHeight - window.innerHeight;
  var path = document.getElementById("path1");
  // Calculate distance along the path the car should be for the current scroll amount
  var pathLen = path.getTotalLength();
  var dist = pathLen * scrollY / maxScrollY;
  var pos = path.getPointAtLength(dist);
  // Calculate position a little ahead of the car (or behind if we are at the end), so we can calculate car angle
  if (dist + 1 <= pathLen) {
    var posAhead = path.getPointAtLength(dist + 1);
    var angle = Math.atan2(posAhead.y - pos.y, posAhead.x - pos.x);
  } else {
    var posBehind = path.getPointAtLength(dist - 1);
    var angle = Math.atan2(pos.y - posBehind.y, pos.x - posBehind.x);
  }
  // Position the car at "pos" totated by "angle"
  var car = document.getElementById("car");
  car.setAttribute("transform", "translate(" + pos.x + "," + pos.y + ") rotate(" + rad2deg(angle) + ")");
}

function rad2deg(rad) {
  return 180 * rad / Math.PI;
}

// Reposition car whenever there is a scroll event
window.addEventListener("scroll", positionCar);

// Position the car initially
positionCar();
```

```css
body {
  min-height: 3000px;
}

svg {
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<svg width="500" height="500" viewBox="0 0 672.474 933.78125">
  <g transform="translate(-54.340447,-64.21875)" id="layer1">
    <path d="m 60.609153,64.432994 c 0,0 -34.345187,72.730986 64.649767,101.015256 98.99494,28.28427 321.2285,-62.62946 321.2285,-62.62946 0,0 131.31984,-52.527932 181.82746,16.16244 50.50763,68.69037 82.04198,196.41856 44.44671,284.86302 -30.25843,71.18422 -74.75128,129.29952 -189.90867,133.34013 -115.15739,4.04061 -72.73099,-153.54318 -72.73099,-153.54318 0,0 42.42641,-129.29953 135.36044,-119.198 92.93404,10.10152 -14.14213,-129.29953 -141.42135,-94.95434 -127.27922,34.34518 -183.84777,80.8122 -206.07112,121.2183 -22.22336,40.40611 -42.06243,226.23742 -26.26397,305.06607 8.77013,43.75982 58.20627,196.1403 171.72594,270.72088 73.8225,48.50019 181.82745,2.02031 181.82745,2.02031 0,0 94.95434,-12.12183 78.7919,-155.56349 -16.16244,-143.44166 -111.68403,-138.77778 -139.9683,-138.77778 -28.28427,0 83.39976,-156.18677 83.39976,-156.18677 0,0 127.27922,-189.90867 107.07617,16.16245 C 634.3758,640.21994 864.69058,888.71747 591.94939,941.2454 319.2082,993.77334 -16.162441,539.20469 153.54319,997.81395"
    id="path1"
    style="fill:none;stroke:#ff0000;stroke-width:4;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1"/>
    <path id="car" d="M-15,-10 L15,0 L -15,10 z" fill="yellow" stroke="red" stroke-width="7.06"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод ответа [How to animate element along svg path on scroll?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50912504/7394871) от участника  [@Paul LeBeau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1292848/paul-lebeau).</sub>

Comment: Возьму под заметку, интересно придумали